# Arguments to path.resolve must be strings Use --force to continue

Tags: eclipse, gruntjs, yeoman

While running the Gruntfile from eclipse, I got the following error. Yeoman also used.

> Running "newer:jshint:all" (newer) task
>
> Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task Warning: Arguments to path.resolve
>   must be strings Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

- grunt-cli - v1.2.0
- grunt - v1.0.1
- node version - v0.10.42

Following is the Gruntfile content for jshint

```
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/spssm/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ],
        test: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '../test/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: ['../test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
        }
    },
```

I have tried few similar cases in stackoverflow but none had anything regarding to **yeoman**

Comment: If you remove `reporter: require('jshint-stylish')`, does the problem persist?

Comment: Didn't  checked it out, since I had some issues with version mismatch in tern components and updating it fixed the problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After some struggling, I was able to correct it. I am adding it here for any future reference.

Seems like when installing tern ide from eclipse, I installed few versions (both eclipse marketplace and install new software). When updating to 1.1.0 from 0.10.0, some components of tern wasn't updated to 1.1.0. By default those are not upgraded and had to set it upgrade once the installer loads the dependencies to install. Apart from that I add grunt and jquery for tern modules.